# How to run a Linux program line by line

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I would like to run a GTK+/C program line by line with some debugger. I have never debugged a Linux program so where can I find instructions to a very beginner on how to debug code? I have just an idea that I have to download the sources from net, compile the project with debug symbols and run sources through DDD or GDB. So can anyone give suggestions how to start studying these subjects and what could be a good debugger to start? I have at least time to learn things.

Comment: Why do you say I haven't accepted any answers? I have got fine suggestions here and I really appreciate that people here have had time to help me on my problems. What else can I do? Add a comment "Thank you very much"?

Comment: No, the tick underneath the vote buttons means that you have accepted that answer as correct.

Comment: Jaska, you need to click the big checkmark next to the best answer on each question you ask.

Comment: Joe, how can I say if answer is correct? If I ask help, the programmer who helped me knows better the subject than me. Often he or she can better say if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks David. I haven't seen that "voting the best answer" property anywhere else so I'm sorry. I try to remember to accept answer as often as I remember.

Comment: BTW, if I have voted some answer to be the best and then I got still better answer, how can I change my opinion?

Comment: @Jaska: You can unaccept an answer and accept a different one, if you so choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also look into nemiver besides DDD, they are good at different things but nemiver is coming along very nicely.

PS. If you're on Ubuntu and you want to step through an application that's installed from the package repository, let's called it some_package, then do this:

1. install the packages "build-essential" and "devscripts"
2. run "sudo apt-get build-dep some_package" to install all things needed to compile that package
3. run "mkdir -p ~/src/some_package ; cd ~/src/some_package" to create a directory for the source code
4. Go into System::Administration::Software Sources and activate the "Source Code" repository
5. run "apt-get source some_package" to download the source code for some_package and put it in the current directory
6. use "cd" to move into the specific app directory, usually something like "some-app-1.2.3"

7A. run "debuild -us -uc -b" to compile the source into a fresh installable .DEB file compiled in release mode *WITHOUT* debug information

or (and this is the central part):

7B. run "MAKEFLAGS=-j6 DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="nostrip noopt parallel=5" CFLAGS="-g3 -O0" debuild -us -uc" to build a deb in debug mode *WITH* debug information

8. use "cd .." to move up one step and then do "ls" and you should see the generated DEB files (multiple binary packages, i.e. DEBs, can be generated from a single source package)
9. sudo "sudo dpkg -i some_package_123.deb" to install the version you just built

Of course, you could optionally modify the code between steps 6 and 7. The nice thing about this method is that it works for pretty much any application. You can use it for Firefox, the Linux kernel, the mesa stack or whatever.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Nemiver to debug gedit and this works. But it calls some GTK+'s libraries so how can I use Nemiver to see what is going to happen inside GTK library? And can I combine valgrind and Nemiver so that I can see if there is a memory leak between lines, say 1 to 350.

Comment: By the way, Ubuntu repositories does not hold the latest code developers uses. Is there some method to compile the latest code they are working on?

Comment: Different upstream projects use different VCS and build systems so there is no universal method for building them. You just have to learn whatever tools that particular project uses, which can be a big hurdle for large projects like Mozilla or Xorg.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using GDB and compiling with gcc -g, or using another debugger.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdb

Comment: @Jaska: The article links to http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/ as a suggested tutorial.

Comment: Wikipedia shouldn't be treated as reliable information. I use it as an easy way of finding reliable sources of information.

Comment: @Mike: I assume you think that because anyone can edit it. However, consider that anyone can add an answer on Stack Overflow, and if they have enough reputation, they can edit existing ones. If that's the case, they should both be about equal when it comes to reliability. I personally find both to be quite reliable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sourceware.org/current/onlinedocs/gdb_toc.html

Full gdb user manual online.