# How can I debug a function in particular file of a running application using gdb?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I have made an application in which there is a file `main.c` which uses a function from the `master.c` file. I would like to debug my application for all functions defined in the `master.c` file by using `gdb tool`. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: What do you mean by the term debug my application? If you refine that term, either an answer below is already answering the question, or we might be able to find a more specific solution. Do you want to automatically set breakpoints on all functions defined in the header? Do you want to inspect memory of all functions? Or do you want to test the functions by comparing them to specific output for given inputs? This might be of help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504965/how-to-run-a-linux-program-line-by-line

Comment: i want automatically set breakpoints on all functions defined in the header..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476002/gdb-set-breakpoint-on-all-functions-in-a-file ?

Comment: This might be of help as well: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715053/how-to-use-gdb-to-debug-a-big-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must compile your program using `-g` flag.

Then you start `gdb your_program` and set break points: `break master.c:37` that will set a break point on master.c, line #37 or you could set breaks at functions: `break foo()`.

Then start your program by `run` and continue with the debugging process, `inspect`, `continue`, `watch`, `display`...

http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Google for more documentation on using gdb.

Of course there is:

[Debug a running program with gdb](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/248/debug-a-currently-running-program-with-gdb/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` as shown [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks)

For Example:

```
break master.c:5
```